# Test jquery for vulnerabilities,

Tags: jquery, security, penetration-testing, cve

I am a bug hunter and founded **CVE-2020-11022** through an *automated* scan on a domain.But there's a problem i don't know how to test jquery manually.You can recommend me blog etc or anything related to it.I shall be very thankful to you.

Answer (score 0):

The following blog post will help you.

[MKSB(en): CVE-2020-11022/CVE-2020-11023: jQuery 3.5.0 Security Fix details](https://mksben.l0.cm/2020/05/jquery3.5.0-xss.html)

You can use this as a reference to read the JavaScript source of that vulnerable website.

Comment: That was really helpful.Thanks.